# Creating a Client-Server application using C# and Python - comments?

Tags: c#, python

I want to move away from the myriad of excel sheets at work and develop a small application for asset tracking.

Initially I'd planned it as a web application, but have had comments from the primary users of the would-be application that they would much prefer a client application as they sometimes can't guarantee internet connectivity while on the road. This is fine.

I'm thinking of developing the server architecture as a RESTful service in Python and having a simple C# client on desktops to fetch and parse the JSON (which is then locally stored for offline access). I only really envisage a dozen people using it.

Can anyone see anything inherently wrong with this setup? I didn't want to have to develop my own socket server as I think further down the line it would be easier to develop other apps that utilise the API (phone apps, perhaps).

Comment: Why not a WCF service? that way your server side is also on .Net and you can have a fully .net architecture.

Comment: I vote for the JSON service. Might be a bit more work, but you can avoid platform lock-in. You can even write a client-side web interface that can use the new HTML5 offline storage. If security is important (or will be in the future), you might want give some thought as to how you might want to implement it. I have written several JSON RPC client-servers and they all work very well for me.

Answer (score 0):

### WCF Web API Anyone?

http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP

WCF Web API satisfies your needs quite well. Not only do you get first class support for .NET clients locally but you can run this REST service locally as a windows service.

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "")]
public List<Contact> Get()
{
    var contacts = new List<Contact>()
        {
            new Contact {ContactId = 1, Name = "Phil Haack"},
            new Contact {ContactId = 2, Name = "HongMei Ge"},
            new Contact {ContactId = 3, Name = "Glenn Block"},
            new Contact {ContactId = 4, Name = "Howard Dierking"},
            new Contact {ContactId = 5, Name = "Jeff Handley"},
            new Contact {ContactId = 6, Name = "Yavor Georgiev"}
        };
    return contacts;
}
```